# Filter values based on a column SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view with the following info:

| id | contractId | opId | opStatus | opDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 201 | Done | 01/01/2024 |
| 2 | 2 | 202 | Processing | 01/01/2024 |
| 3 | 2 | 203 | Done | 01/01/2024 |
| 4 | 3 | 301 | Waiting | 01/01/2024 |
| 5 | 3 | 302 | Processing | 02/01/2024 |
| 6 | 4 | 401 | Waiting | 05/01/2024 |
| 7 | 4 | 402 | Waiting | 06/01/2024 |
| 8 | 5 | 501 | Done | 01/01/2024 |

What I need is to filter the data based on the next criteria:

1. If `opStatus` for any operation in contract is `Done` - take all lines with this status and the same date
2. If not, if `opStatus` for any operation in contract is `Processing` - take all lines with this status and the same date (like the first criteria)
3. If not take operation with the earliest `opDate`

So after all this steps I should have a table with a result:

| id | contractId | opId | opStatus | opDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 201 | Done | 01/01/2024 |
| 3 | 2 | 203 | Done | 01/01/2024 |
| 5 | 3 | 302 | Processing | 02/01/2024 |
| 6 | 4 | 401 | Waiting | 05/01/2024 |
| 8 | 5 | 501 | Done | 01/01/2024 |

What would be a possibly required SQL? Database is Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT id, contractId, opId, opStatus, opDate
FROM   table_name 
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY contractId
         ORDER BY opDate, id
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN ( ^ ({- any_row*? -} done)+
                 | ^ ({- any_row*? -} processing)+
                 | ^ any_row
                 )
         DEFINE
           done AS  opStatus = 'Done'
                AND TRUNC(opDate) = TRUNC(FIRST(done.opDate)),
           processing AS opStatus = 'Processing'
                AND TRUNC(opDate) = TRUNC(FIRST(processing.opDate))
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, contractId, opId, opStatus, opDate) AS
SELECT 1, 2, 201, 'Done',       DATE '2024-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 202, 'Processing', DATE '2024-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, 203, 'Done',       DATE '2024-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3, 301, 'Waiting',    DATE '2024-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3, 302, 'Processing', DATE '2024-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 4, 401, 'Waiting',    DATE '2024-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 4, 402, 'Waiting',    DATE '2024-01-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 5, 501, 'Done',       DATE '2024-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | CONTRACTID | OPID | OPSTATUS | OPDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 201 | Done | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2 | 203 | Done | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 3 | 302 | Processing | 2024-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 6 | 4 | 401 | Waiting | 2024-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 8 | 5 | 501 | Done | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ijTu3c66)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, works like a charm! And if I want to keep only first input with the same status how can I modify this request?

Comment: Is it possible to get the earliest one out of the same lines for contract? @MT0

Comment: @Evillain If you only want the first value from the pattern (rather than all values) then remove the `+` characters from the pattern (you can also remove the `AND TRUNC(...` lines from the `DEFINE` clause as they would then be unnecessary but they also won't break the query if they remain) [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XUOLXXpR)

Comment: Thanks @MT0 Both solutions work as intended

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function as follows:

```
Select t.* from
(Select t.*,
       Count(case when opstatus = 'Done' then 1 end) over (partition by contractid) as donecnt,
       Count(case when opstatus = 'Processing' then 1 end) over (partition by contractid) as processingcnt,
       Row_number() over (partition by contractid order by opdate) as rn
  From your_table t) t
Where (donecnt > 0 and opstatus = 'Done')
Or (processingcnt > 0 and donecnt = 0 and opstatus = 'Processing')
Or (processingcnt = 0 and donecnt = 0 and rn = 1)
order by id;
```

Comment: The OP's requirement is "If opStatus for any operation in contract is Done - take all lines with this status and the same date" Does this filter rows based on date?

Comment: @ORA-01017 thanks for the answer. If I want to keep only first input with the same status with the earliest date how I can edit the query?